# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut "blink" on Chrome, works fine on FireFox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Please see my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gt4Rj/

I want the thing to fade out and then fade in. It works perfectly as I want it to be on Firefox and IE. But it shows a weird "blink" on Chrome. 
I've made fadeOut and fadeIn as simple as possible. But nothing seems to be the reason.

HTML:

```
<body>
    bbbbbbb
</body>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('body')
.addClass('fixed-top fadeIn')
        .fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-top {
  background:transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;

}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}  
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}


.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backword;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

Comment: Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/gt4Rj/4/
Why do you need .fadeIn class?

Comment: I will just remove that `.fadeIn` in your CSS ....

Comment: @Turgut: Thanks for the comment. That is intended for Chrome. Though I removed it, it still doesn't work well as it is in Firefox. According to your jsFiddle, yours still blink at the very beginning in Chrome but not in Firefox. Please see yours fiddle in Firefox and in Chrome. You'll see the difference: In Chrome, it blinks once at the very beginning, as in Firefox, it starts directly from "FadeOut".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused due to animation-duration css that you have added for `.fadeIn`. Remove duration css and everything will work perfectly.

```
 .fadeIn {
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backword;
 -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt4Rj/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But according to your jsFiddle, yours still blink at the very beginning in Chrome but not in Firefox. Please see yours fiddle in Firefox and in Chrome. You'll see the difference: In Chrome, it blinks once at the very beginning, as in Firefox, it starts directly from "FadeOut".

Comment: That is happening because of dom is getting first loaded and then fade  out fade in.You will even find the content to be flickering if you remove the js code.

Comment: But it doesn't happen in Firefox though. Why is that? Thank you for your help @Milind Anantwar

Comment: Anyways, it helped. Thanks @Milind Anantwar

Answer (score 0):

I don't think wire CSS3 animation with jQuery animation is a good idea. Code below might help, just simply using jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

```
var $body = jQuery('body')
$body.fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $body.fadeIn(1000); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Though I use pure jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut, it still blinks once before it starts to "fadeOut" in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: Did you remove your css? Remove your css before you have a try, because your css will influence animation. @Joanne

Comment: Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/h3pjb/ See it in Chrome and in Firefox and you'll see the difference. Please run it again if you miss the very first blink in Chrome.

Comment: @Joanne Remove `.addClass('fixed-top fadeIn')` and try again. And `fadeIn` should be in callback function and not supposed to be called in chain.

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pEP27/ ? It still blinks at the beginning in Chrome.